# Disabling Cursor "Snap To" Behavior on Overview Map

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

On both, the Xbox and the PS3 version, when on the overview map the cursor snaps to hotspot icons as soon as the cursor is near enough. it is very hard to precisely select one if several icons are very close together or even overlapping. Is there an option to turn this snapping behaviour off?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is being asked here. What is it you want to turn off?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful. I have no idea what a 'click' is in this context.

Comment: Hi, @Supahshadow.  I have voted to close your question because it's not very clear exactly what you're asking.  Once you have clarified, we can reopen and answer it.

Comment: Now that sounds much clearer!

Comment: The title could use some work though.

Comment: I don't recall it being an option to disable the snap-to cursor on the map.

Comment: @Supahshadow Sorry, no. You can't turn that terrible snap-to behavior off. I LOVE so much about the gameplay in Reckoning, but this is a detail they didn't get right.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is **no option for turning this off**. Try moving the cursor to the desired spot *from different sides*. If the cursor still snaps to a wrong spot try *flicking the stick*. It may take some time but got me where I wanted to most of the time.